# Is it common to say "My salary is good" or "My pay is good"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

It seems that "**pay**" is more common in everyday English and salary is way too formal.

I feel like "**salary**" is used more in accounting or formal documents.

I don't know why not many Google search results of "Salary vs Pay".

Is it common to say "**My salary is good**" or "**My pay is good**"?

When do we say "**My salary is good**" or "**My pay is good**"?

Comment: "I'm on a good salary" sounds more natural to me than "My salary is good".

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the intuition that "salary" is very formal.

The distinction in definitions is that "pay" is more general: any time you receive money for doing stuff. "Salary" is more specific: you're being paid money in fixed intervals (say, every month, or every two weeks) according to terms in your job contract. So there are times when talking about "salary" wouldn't be appropriate, and you'd have to talk about "pay".

If I am talking about a specific job that I have, where I negotiated for my salary, I'd be more likely to use "salary" over "pay". I think saying "**My salary is good**" is not wrong, but for some reason "**My salary is high**" sounds more natural to me.

Also, in cases where "salary" does not apply, I'd be more likely to say "**The pay is good**" rather than "**My pay is good**". These mean different things: saying "the pay is good" is talking about the amount *anyone* could get for that particular job. But those are precisely the cases where "pay" is the better term over "salary". Also, "the pay is good" is a very common phrase.

(In case it turns out to matter, my intuition comes from American English.)

Comment: In Britain - salaries are earned by professional people like teachers, doctors, accountants etc. People who do unskilled work tend to be paid "wages". "Pay" is more usually associated with wages and people at the lower end of the income scale. Though this is by no means always the case. A chief executive may well complain about his "pay".

Comment: So it looks like the distinction between kinds of income becomes only more precise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the rest of the world, but in Canada (and probably the US):

- "pay" is what you get paid at the end of each day or week based on the number of hours you worked.
  It's an hourly wage, typically received by lower-skilled workers.
  *When the bell rings, you drop what you're doing and go home.*
- "salary" is a fixed amount that you get paid at the end of each month, regardless of the number of hours worked (e.g. March is 3 days longer than February).
  It's typically received by skilled professionals, who will often work a few extra hours at the end of the day to finish off a project, or who will take a few extra hours for a "business lunch".
  *You go home when the job is finished.*

Answer (score 1):

The word "remuneration" refers to the concept of *what-you-are-given* in exchange for your work.  This is a very stuffy and technical word that nobody uses (except for lawyers).

The words "salary" and "wage" and "pay" are often synonymous with "remuneration" but there are small differences in meaning which make distinctions between the terms in particular situations.

---

The primary cultural phenomenon to remember is a distinction between "salaried" employees and "hourly" employees. (This is the U.S. terminology but I believe there are similarities elsewhere.)

In general, if you are contracted as an "hourly" employee your "wage" will typically be quoted as an hourly rate (e.g. $15/hour) which will then be doled-out based upon the number of hours you have worked since your previous payment. (Usually, every-other-week or bi-monthly, but sometimes weekly or even daily.)  If you work "overtime" then you are likely to receive additional "bonus" enumeration based upon local laws.

By contrast, if you are contracted as a "salaried" employee your "salary" will typicaly be quoted like a yearly lump-sum (i.e. "$60,000 per year") but it will actually be doled-out evenly on a bi-weekly or bi-monthly basis (i.e. $60,000 per year = $2,300 per 2-weeks or $2,500 bi-monthly).  You will be paid the same amount each few weeks, regardless of whether you work the weekly-minimum-number-of-hours or put in significant "overtime". (Local "overtime" laws typically have exemptions for salaried employees.)

In summary, hourly employees are paid a wage (e.g. $15/hour) whereas salaried employees are paid a salary (e.g. $60,000/year) and those two concepts are considered to be distinct.

---

In effect, this means that "My pay is good." and "My wage is good." and "My salary is good." are not precisely equivalent.

If Adam is an hourly employee making $25/hr and regularly works a full 40 hours plus a bit of overtime... it might not be uncommon for his bi-weekly paychecks to be approximately $2300 (before tax).

If Bob is a salaried employee making $60,000 per year (working 40 hours weekly plus maybe some occasional "unpaid" overtime)... it might not be uncommon for his bi-weekly paychecks to be approximately $2300 (before tax).

In our example, both Adam and Bob are making $2300 every two weeks... and (if they are not living in a too-expensive city) they might each conclude "My pay is good." because they are happy with their paychecks.

However, it would be weird for Adam to say "My salary is good." because he is paid an hourly wage and not a salary.  And similarly, it would be strange for Bob to say "My wage is good." because he is paid on salary and not a wage.